# Runtime error when binding data to GridView

Tags: asp.net

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using sampledbModel;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
     private sampledbEntities db = new sampledbEntities();

     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {

     }

     protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         GridView1.DataSource = db.contacts;
         GridView1.DataBind();
     }
}
```

It shows me `System.NotSupportedException`. Below is the snapshot for it - I am using entity framework to perform operations on database.

[image]

Comment: Did my answer help you out ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your exception is thrown on the button click event (it is not clear from your original post)

You must load the data in to memory by calling `.ToList()` when setting the `DataSource` of the `GridView`.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.DataSource = db.contacts.ToList();
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: now after the button click event i get the System.InvalidOperationException